# program doesnt enter if condition , gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, if-statement, segmentation-fault

the code is somewhat like

```
cin >> n  // test cases
for( n times )
{ 
 .....
  for(;;)
    {
     getline(cin,inp) //inp is supposed to be +,-,*,\,0-9,if simply enter pressed program passes out of loop
      for(;;)
      {
       if (inp[0] == '*')
       {
        do stuff...
       }

       if (inp[0] == '\')
       {
        do stuff...
       }         

       if (inp[0] == '+') \\ this is where the problem occurs
       {
        do stuff...
       } 
    .....
    .....
        }
    }
return 0 ;
}
```

[here is the actual code with some comments](http://ideone.com/0aVKmo) ,i have tried converting infix to postfix inn the program . here's my input and the problem...

```
>1          //1 test case


>3           //if condition as it should entered line 124

>inp[0] 3   //confirms 3 is inp[0]

>*          //works as it should (if condn entered line 37)

>inp[0] *   

>/          //works as it should

>inp[0] /

>+          //problem!! if condition not entered even though it should 
            //as inp[0] == '+' (line 61)
>inp[0] +   //confirmation inp[0] is + right before if condition checked

>Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I tried my level best to explain the code and the problem briefly, i ask this question as the problem looks totally ambiguos to me , any explanation needed pls tell me . 
Also , give any suggestion to debug problems like these , i have got such errors before and i cant everytime ask here. Give any reccomendation to an beginner->amatuer coder for solving such segmentation faults . 
thanks and regards

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`  Please don't do this.  Include the correct headers.

Comment: To decrease compilation time ?

Comment: There is no such header as `bits/stdc++.h`in standard C++.  What *is* in standard C++ are `<vector>`, `<iostream>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

General advice:

use breakpoints and other features provided by your ide to find your problem.

It's been decades since c++ was born, there won't be such bug.

diag:

for debug message, change `cout<<"+ detected";` to `cout<<"+ detected"<<endl ;`. `endl` for flushing the buffer and put it to screen.

it do enters your if-condition and failed at

`if (stk.top() == '*' || stk.top() == '/' && stk.size() != 0 )`

if `stk.top()` succeed, of course `stk.size() != 0`. It's not empty.

if `stk.empty() == true`, `stk.top()` will try to get something from an empty stack and throws seg fault back.

and just few lines below this there's another `if-statement` with the same mistake:

`else if (stk.top() == '-' && stk.size() != 0 )`

I changed these line and code works for your input sequence `1 3 * / +`.

Comment: Hi..I want to clear a few things..1st. No segmentation fault is thrown when * is input 2nd. I put a condition to check stack.size!=0 before using stk.top as I knew there would be a seg error3rd. The problem is when '+' is entered as inp ,it is then a segmentation fault is thrown...pls I did my work do recheck what I wrote earlier, it may not be such a simple error

Comment: @95_96 when * is the 2nd input it is pushed into `stk` then `stk` is not empty, the `if-statement` I mentioned won't be trouble any longer. another seg fault is from only few lines below that if I mentioned for the same reason. check your code carefully.

Comment: The 1st input which is a number of type char is pushed back into a vector called eqn , it never goes into stack stk

Comment: I tried a few more things still isn't working, I get your point exactly and I had it in mind while writing, it would be very helpful if you could post your edited code somehow..thanks